# A fixed-point theorem by Zamfirescu

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I am having a trouble with understanding the proof of a fixed-point theorem by Zamfirescu.

Could somebody please explain how the inequality in [the inner, pink rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bVoJ.jpg) is obtained from the previous one? I see no reason for this to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this just arithmetic? Expand the RHS and collect terms, giving $(1-\beta)d(f^{n+1}(x_0),f^{n+2}(x_0))$ on the LHS and $\beta d(f^n(x_0),f^{n+1}(x_0))$ on the right. Since $\beta < \frac{1}{2}$, $1-\beta>0$ and the result follows.

Comment: Of course! Oh dear...